# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I am trying to resolve this TypeError but have not been able to. Below is the code it is pointing to. I have tried assigning a var to it as some other similar posts have mentioned but no luck. ):

```
const emailReducer = (state, action) => {
if (action.type === 'USER_INPUT') {
return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.includes('@') }
}
if (action.type === 'INPUT_BLUR') {
return { value: state.value, isValid: state.val.includes('@') }
}
return { value: '', isValid: false };
};
```

Comment: And what is the value you are dispatching in your action? The error is clearly informing you that `action.val` is undefined. Can you include all relevant code in your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you sure about this: `isValid: state.val.includes('@')`? It looks like it's `state.value` instead of `state.val`, or maybe `action.val`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can see `state.val` is undefined, thus lacking `includes` method. It seems the value should be addressed as `state.value` instead.